# Push object into array and *ngFor it

Tags: angular

When i click button addRoom i want add to araay an Object . And loop this in view . But data in my array repeated  . Sorry for my english if you can't understand may ask me in comment . Thanks for reading!

my code :
html

```
<table class="booking-table">
<tr>
    <th>ROOM</th>
    <th>5 + YRS</th>
    <th>0-5 YRS</th>
    <th>PER NIGHT</th>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor="let item of Room">
    <td>{{item.room}}</td>
    <td>
        <select [ngModel]="item.audutModel" (ngModelChange)="AddAdults($event)">
            <option value="1">
                1 Adults
            </option>
            <option value="2">
                2 Adults
            </option>
            <option value="3">
                3 Adults
            </option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select [ngModel]="item.childModel" (ngModelChange)="AddChild($event)">
            <option value="1">
                1 Child
            </option>
            <option value="2" *ngIf="  this.Adults == 1 || this.Adults == 2 ">
                2 Child
            </option>
            <option value="3"  *ngIf="  this.Adults == 1 ">
                3 Child
            </option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>{{item.pricePN}}</td>
</tr>
<button type="" (click)="AddRoom()">add room</button>
```

ts code :

```
  AddAdults(Adults){
    this.Adults = Adults;
    console.log(this.Adults)
    this.pricePerAd = 200;
    this.price = 1000 + Adults*this.pricePerAd;

  }

  AddChild(child){
  this.pricePerCh = 100;
  this.price += child*this.pricePerCh;


  }



 AddRoom(){


    this.audutModel = "audut";
    this.childModel = "child";
    this.RoomNumber = this.RoomNumber + 1 ;

    this.audutModel =   this.audutModel + this.RoomNumber;
    this.childModel = this.childModel + this.RoomNumber;


   this.object.room = this.RoomNumber;
   this.object.audut = this.audutModel;
   this.object.child = this.childModel;
   this.object.pricePN = this.price;

   this.Room.push(this.object)
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to `this.object` everywhere, so that automatically means that all objects in the array are the same. You need to have each item as an unique item to be able to differentiate them.

Here's a ***really rough*** example you should improve and work further with. Also notice the naming convention, e.g I'm referring to `rooms = []` instead of `Room = []`. Also consider making an **[Interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)** for `Room` model.

Okay, when adding a new room, create an empty object and increment a local variable `idx`, which refers to the index in the array, and after adding a room, let's just increment that:

```
addRoom(){
  this.rooms.push({room: this.idx+1, adult: null, child: null, pricePN: null})
  this.idx++;
}
```

In your template, use two-way-binding and when you are adding an adult (and child), this way we won't need to call a separate function to add the number of child or parent in that room. But when changes are made, call `calculate` instead, passing the index (`i`), which has been declared in the iteration of `rooms`

```
<select [(ngModel)]="item.adult" (change)="calculate(i)">
```

and the `calculate`-function just summing up the amount with the prices you have:

```
calculate(index) {
  this.rooms[index].pricePN = 
        1000+this.rooms[index].adult*200+this.rooms[index].child*100;
}
```

You had quite a lot of variables, from which you can basically remove all, except the declaration of the array.

Here's a **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview)** to play with.